# Multiplicar Items de un Array() PHP

Tags: array, php7

(Actualizado = corrección de array)
Gente muy buenas de nuevo yo por acá, estoy atascado en mi proyecto en algo que parece ser una bobada, pero que me tienes ya con un par de canas, Tengo el siguiente `array()`

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 672670
            [cuota] => 2.37
            [equipoL] => HIFK Elsinki
            [equipoV] => SJK
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => visitante
            [superCuota] => 2.37
            [total] => 0
            [fecha_evento] => 2021/08/06 10:30:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 675745
            [cuota] => 2.80
            [equipoL] => Afturelding
            [equipoV] => Thor Akureyri
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => visitante
            [superCuota] => 2.80
            [total] => 0
            [fecha_evento] => 2021/08/06 13:00:00
        )

)
```

Aplicando la solución de la respuesta #1, valido primero, Si solo hay un elemento en el `array()` `$multiplicar` es igual a la `'cuota'` de ese único elemento, de lo contrario multiplicame todas las cuotas de los elementos que hallan en el `array()` así:

```
 foreach ($_SESSION['carrito'] as $cuotas) {
            if (count( $_SESSION['carrito']) == 1) {
                $megaCuota = $cuotas['cuota'];
            }else{
                $megaCuota *= $cuotas['cuota'];
            }
            
        }
    
    echo $megaCuota;
```

cuando `$_SESSION['carrito']== 1` efectivamente `$megaCuota` me toma el valor de la cuota de ese unico elemento.
Pero cuando `$_SESSION['carrito']` tiene mas de 1 elemento `$megaCuota` me da como resultado 0.

NOTA: si cambio `*=` por `+=` el resultado de $megaCuota si me realiza la suma, pero la multiplicacion da 0, no entiendo por que.

Lo que necesito es miltiplicar todos los elementos 'cuota', alguien me puede guiar por favor?

Comment: Agrega aquello que hayas intentado por favor

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que hacer un foreach del array

```
<?php
    $array = array(
    array('evento' => 672670,
            'cuota' => 2.37,
            'equipoL' => 'HIFK Elsinki',
            'equipoV' => 'SJK',
            'tipo' => 'Match Winner',
            'apostadoA' => 'visitante',
            'superCuota'=> 2.37,
            'total' => 0,
            'fecha_evento' => '2021/08/06 10:30:00'
            ),
array('evento' => 675745,
            'cuota' => 2.80,
            'equipoL' => 'Afturelding',
            'equipoV' => 'Thor Akureyri',
            'tipo' => 'Match Winner',
      

          'apostadoA' => 'visitante',
                'superCuota' => 2.80,
                'total' => 0,
                'fecha_evento' => '2021/08/06 13:00:00',
                ),
      
    );

   $multiplicacion=0;
foreach ( $array as $row){
    if($row==$array[0]){
        
    $multiplicacion = $row['cuota'];
    }else{
         $multiplicacion *=$row['cuota'];
    }
}
echo $multiplicacion;
    
    ?>
```

ver el [ejemplo](https://paiza.io/projects/Ii4oBcS_9lL96LiTFsOqlQ)

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por la respuesta, es correcta para el array que había publicado, pero me equivoqué, acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el array correcto, he intentado aplicar tu solución a este pero $multiplicar me da igual 0

Comment: dame un momento

Comment: Listo amigo muchas gracias

Comment: puedes colocar esta respuesta como la correcta si llego a lo que necesita muchas gracias

Comment: claro amigo inmediatamente